# A question on size of solutions to a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, information-theory, fibonacci-numbers

For given $A, B \in Z$, consider the sequences

$P(n) = P(n-2) + P(n-1), P(0) = 1, P(1) = 0,$

$Q(n) = Q(n-2) + Q(n-1), Q(0) = 0, Q(1) = 1,$

and the cumulative sequences $\Sigma P(n), \Sigma Q(n), A.\Sigma P(n) + B.\Sigma Q(n)$

and the $GCD$ sequence defined by $GCD(\Sigma P(n) + \Sigma Q(n))$.

$$\array{
A.P(n)+B.Q(n) & n & P(n) & Q(n) & ΣP(n) & ΣQ(n) & GCD(ΣP(n), ΣQ(n)) \\
A & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
       B & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  A +  B & 2 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
  A + 2B & 3 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
 2A + 3B & 4 & 2 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 1 \\
 3A + 5B & 5 & 3 & 5 & 8 & 12 & 4 \\
 5A + 8B & 6 & 5 & 8 & 13 & 20 & 1 \\
 8A +13B & 7 & 8 & 13 & 21 & 33 & 3 \\
13A +21B & 8 & 13 & 21 & 34 & 54 & 2 \\
21A +34B & 9 & 21 & 34 & 55 & 88 & 11 \\
\dots & \dots & \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots& \dots \\
}$$

For $n \in Z, z > 1, z \in Z_{+}$ consider the equation,

$$A.\Sigma P(n) + B.\Sigma Q(n) = z$$

When $GCD(\Sigma P(n), \Sigma Q(n)) = 1$, we can determine the minimal $A, B$ using the Euclidean Algorithm.

**Questions:**

1. When $GCD(\Sigma P(n), \Sigma Q(n)) = 1$, is $\log(z) \gt \log(n) + \log(A) + \log(B)$ for any $n>1, z \in Z$?
2. When $GCD(\Sigma P(n), \Sigma Q(n)) = g \ne 1$ and $g | z$, is $\log(z) \gt \log(g) + \log(n) + \log(A) + \log(B)$ for any $n>1, z \in Z$. (*Note:* $g | z$ is required for the equation $A.\Sigma P(n) + B.\Sigma Q(n) = z$ to have a solution in integers)

Comment: I noticed  that your $P,Q,\Sigma P$ squence are Fibonacci, and that $\Sigma Q$ is Fibonacci minus 1. Finally, your $GCD$ sequence is [OEIS sequence A2102009](http://oeis.org/A210209).

Comment: The column for $A\Sigma P(n)+B\Sigma Q(n)$ appears to be $AP(n)+BQ(n)$.

Comment: Ah yes, typo. I have edited the question. Thank you @Chrystomath.

Comment: If $z=1$, then Question 1's inequality is obviously false. When you ask "Is ... for any $n>1$ do you mean "does there exist an $n>1$ such that ..." or "prove ... for all $n>1$ "? Also, $A,B$ are positive/negative so do you mean $\log|A|$ and $\log|B|$?

Comment: For small values of $z$ there are *no* positive integers $A$ and $B$ such that
$$z=A\Sigma P(n)+B\Sigma Q(n).$$
By *"minimal $A$ and $B$"* do you mean $A$ and $B$ with $|A|+|B|$ minimal?
Also, if $A$ or $B$ is negative then $\log A$ or $\log B$ does not exist.

Comment: @Servaes: $A, B$ is minimal in the sense they are solutions found through the Euclidean algorithm. Yes, A, B are positive as clarified in the edit and comment above.

Comment: @vvgiri The Euclidean algorithm does not always return positive coefficients. Consider the simple case $3A+4B=1$, corresponding to $n=3$.

Comment: You are right. I intended for |A|, |B| minimal. I see your answer. I'll correct the Qn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a natural number $n>1$ and integer $z$, and integers $A$ and $B$ such that $z=A\Sigma P(n)+B\Sigma Q(n)$, the inequality
$$\log z>\log n+\log A+\log B,$$
is equivalent to $z>nAB$, or equivalently
$$(\Sigma P(n)- nB)(\Sigma Q(n)-nA)<\Sigma P(n)\Sigma Q(n).$$
Clearly $\Sigma Q(n)>n$ for $n\geq3$ and so for $A=1$ and any $B>\tfrac{\Sigma P(n)}{n}$ we have
$$(\Sigma P(n)- nB)(\Sigma Q(n)-nA)=(\Sigma P(n)-nB)(\Sigma Q(n)-n)<0<\Sigma P(n)\Sigma Q(n).$$
So for any integer $n\geq3$ you can take any integer $B>\tfrac{\Sigma P(n)}{n}$ and take
$$z=\Sigma P(n)+B\Sigma Q(n).$$
Note that the pair of coefficients $(A,B)=(1,B)$ has $|A|+|B|$ minimal because $\Sigma Q(n)\geq\Sigma P(n)$.